# How to detect swipes on a lightning/aura page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, mobile

I have multiple tabs for users to switch between. For mobile users ideally they could swipe left/right and see the information on each tab. How can I do this in an aura page? I tried it a variety of ways but aura seems to only support regular clicks.

Comment: You need to use touch events. Have you tried that? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: use touchpunch https://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ended up finding the answer, I used **ontouchmove** for detecting swipe events,
event returns a touch object in an event.touches array

edit:

```
Index.cmp
 <div  ontouchmove="{!c.touchmove}"><!--start touchcontainer-->


IndexController.js
touchmove: function(component, event, helper) {     
         if(!event.touches || event.touches.length == 0)return;
         var xmoved =  event.touches[0].clientX
        //do stuff
},
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample code here as how were you able to achieve this? This will be helpful for others in similar situation.